# Who proposed Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion, area-51, askubuntu

I heard that Ask Ubuntu is part of Stack Exchange so I want to know who proposed Ask Ubuntu?

Comment: You can always find the proposal's information on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7716/ubuntu).

Answer (score 7):

The [Area 51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7716/ubuntu) for the site shows that this guy, [Evan](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/4064/evan).

Like most Stack Exchange sites, someone proposes a new topic on Area 51, gets enough followers for it to get it launched. Ask Ubuntu went through the same exact process.